# Scala:Constant properties val or def

Tags: scala, constants

I've got an integer Coordinate Structure for a Hex grid, that I'm porting from C# to Scala as follows:

```
object Cood
{
  def Up = new Cood(0, 2)
  def UpRight = new Cood(1, 1)
  def DownRight = new Cood(1,- 1)
  def Down = new Cood(0, - 2)
  def DownLeft = new Cood(- 1, - 1)
  def UpLeft = new Cood(- 1, + 1)
  def None = new Cood(0, 0)
}

class Cood(val x: Int, val y: Int)
{
   //more code
}
```

As there were no constants for non basic types they were static get properties. In Scala should I implement them as def s or val s or does it not matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement them as `val`.  The `def` keyword defines a method, so every time it is called, the method will be executed.  In other words, with `val` the `Cood` object will be created once and stored, but with `def` a new copy will be created every time you go to access it.

If you are worried about creating object that may not be used, then you should try `lazy val`, which is a val that is only populated the first time it is accessed.

Comment: No it will be used. Does that mean that apart from the initial overhead it will be as efficent as a literal constant?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably implement your Cood class as a [case class](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html):

```
case class Cood(x: Int, y: Int)
```

That's it, no need for additional getters / setters, equality method, toString, or extractor for pattern matching.

If you just want it as a normal class, however, just write `class Cood(val x: Int, val y: Int)`.

Comment: @Rich if you write `val x` as per your edit then you get getters / setters automatically, so there's no question of needing additional methods. But case classes give you them with or without the `val`.

Comment: @Luigi declared as a val, you won't have setter.